# LibGdx, Particle effect : keep rotating indidual particles emitted

Tags: libgdx, rotation, editor, particle-system

Im using 2D Particle Editor from libGdx. There are ways to intilaise rotation of indivual partices emitted. But those particles doesnt keep on rotating after they are spawned.. They do move  How do i do that? Is there a way to set Rotate Action on individual particles?

- Tried setting Rotation in particle editor.. This sets only the intial rotation with which particle is created..

Answer (score 0):

In particle editor, Emitter properties, Rotation, there is a  Life graph. The blue line in life graph by default is a straight line.. Changing it to a slanting line does the trick.. This tells emitter to rotate it as life of particle goes.. You can set it to slanting line, V shape or W shape as you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).